# Does a jupyter terminal live in the same environment as my anaconda environment(s)?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

This wasn't an issue in the past, as I've been using Anaconda for a few years now, but I can't find much documentation on what I'm trying to debug/educate myself on regarding the newest version of Anaconda. I installed the latest Anaconda (Anaconda3 for Python3), created a new Python 3 environment

```
conda create -n env3 python=3
```

conda installed jupyterlab, and then open up jupyter lab. In the past, I would open up a terminal within jupyter, install the desired packages, and then open up a Python script with a Python 3 kernel. This has been my workflow for quite some time (in both jupyter notebook and jupyter lab), and now it seems to function differently. Here's what I see, start to finish:

[before opening jupyter lab]

```
$ conda activate env3
(env3) $ python --version
Python 3.7.3
(env3) $ python
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/repos/bin/python
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/repos/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/repos/lib/python3.7', '/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/repos/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/repos/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

[opens jupyter lab, opens new Terminal]

```
(base) $ python --version
Python 2.7.1
(base) $ python
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/bin/python
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

It seems like I can still install packages into my environments before opening jupyter, and use them in scripts with the kernel of that environment, but the jupyter terminal is reflecting different information, and therefore I can't install packages through the jupyter terminal.

Additional note: in the past, I would open up my different environments, and open up jupyter on different ports per-environment. It seems like it may defeat the purpose kernels, but I could still install packages in the jupyter terminal to each environment safely with my past method.

It seems like things have changed with the latest Anaconda or conda update, and I know there may be a lot of layers to what could be going wrong, so pointing me in any direction to help resolve this would be massively helpful.

Comment: what is the output of `jupyter kernelspec list` ?

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez 
```Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/user/anaconda3/envs/env3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Comment: Thought I didn't figure out the answer to my question, I did end up getting my environments to function, although my workflow is a bit different. I re-installed Anaconda, setup my environments with kernels as intended, but instead of opening JupyterLab from the terminal, I opened it from the Anaconda Navigator. Everything I see posted above is still the same, but the environments work fine within JupyterLab.